# If $a>0$ prove that $\lim a^{1/n} =1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $a>0$ prove that $\lim a^{1/n} =1$. 
One of my tries was to find a number $N \in R / |a^{1/n}-1|< \epsilon, \forall n\ge N$
so I started by $|a^{1/N}-1|< \epsilon$ then separated the inequality for $a>1$
and then I got $a^{1/N}-1<\epsilon$, then $1/N<log_a(\epsilon -1)$, then I was trying to find a way to make sure that $log_a(\epsilon -1)> 0$ but I couldn't.

Comment: Questions like these, limits involving exponents in real analysis, are extremely dependent on context, as there are a several viable ways to construct exponential functions. What kinds of results do you have about exponents? Are you allowed to use logarithms? Do you assume logarithms and exponentials are continuous? What tools do you have at your disposal?

Comment: Bernoulli's inequality?

Comment: You might try $\lim_{x\to 0}e^x=1$ first and then $a^{1/n}=e^{ln(a)/n}$.  This will work for all $a\gt 0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I was thinking of doing that, but we would be appealing to continuity and I wasn't sure whether we could do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if $a>1$, Prove that $\lim a^{1\over n}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861197/if-a1-prove-that-lim-a1-over-n-1)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2681154/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2724526/42969

Answer (score 5):

For $a=1$ the claim holds, because constant sequence will have the same limit. Assume $a>1$, then $a^{1/n} > 1$ (why?). Put $x_n := a^{1/n} -1 > 0, n\in\mathbb N$. By the binomial theorem
$$a = (1+x_n)^n > nx_n  \implies 0 < x_n < \frac{a}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$
For $0<a<1$ put $b := \frac{1}{a} >1$ and 
$$\sqrt[n]{a} = \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{b}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1. $$

---

Alternatively, as suggested by @herb steinberg, we could use
$$ \frac{\ln a}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\qquad (a>0)$$
which implies due to continuity of the exponential function
$$ a^{1/n} = e^{\ln a/n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^0 = 1. $$

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice proof involving the AM-GM inequality and the squeeze theorem.

Let $a\ge 1$. Write $a=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}\cdot 1\cdots 1$ (with $n-2$ ones). By the AM-GM we have
$$1\le a^{1/n}=(\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}\cdot 1\cdots 1)^{1/n}\le \frac{2\sqrt{a}+n-2}{n}\to 1.$$
The squeeze theorem concludes the proof.

The case $0<a<1$ is the immediate consequence of the case $a\ge 1$ (use $1/a$ instead of $a$).

**Remark.** In the same way one can show that $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Show:$$\left|a^{1/n}-1\right|=\frac{\left|a-1\right|}{1+a^{1/n}+a^{2/n}+\cdots+a^{(n-1)/n}}\leq \frac{|a-1|}{n\min(1,a)}$$